# Read file to a list and then write the list to another file Python

Tags: python

```
list1 = []
with open('/home/yan/Desktop/a.txt','r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        list1 += data[:2]
list2 = list(set(list1)


with open('/home/yan/Desktop/docs.txt','w') as f2:
    for item in list2:
      print>>f2,item
```

I'm trying to read the file `a.txt` to `list1`, delete some replicates and save it to `list2`, and then write `list2` to `docs.txt`, but I get the Syntax error on the second `with open`, I don't know what's the problem here. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!

The shell reports error on line7, and the message is "There's an error in your program:invalid syntax"

Comment: `with open('/home/yan/Desktop/a', 'r') as f1`

Comment: seriously, you do not choose extensions for your file names?

Comment: Show, don't tell: instead of telling us you're getting an error, copy and paste the complete traceback into your question, so we can see the details.  Copy and paste your code exactly, too (copy, paste, and then hit control-K or select the {} button to format), as right now there's an indentation error.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SyntaxErro` is coming from:

```
list2 = list(set(list1)
```

You forgot to close the parens around this expression.

This should be:

```
list2 = list(set(list1))
```

Comment: well, seems it is...I kept focusing on the error message on with, but simply ignored the obvious error.

Comment: Often you need to look above the code that it's complaining about when it comes to **Syntax Errors**.